# Searching through DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, search, datagridview

I have a datagridview with three columns (ID, Name, Address). It's bound to a database that contains around 500 items.

I want to be able to search the gridview for data given in a text box, and then highlight it.

If possible, pressing the Next button should find the next match, and the Reset button should clear all selections (nothing highlighted).

Please advise how to do it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add a search box and search button in the page. OnClick of the search button, search the datatable for the results and keep the result in the session. then on the bound event of grid, highlight the first row of from the search result set (which can be done by matching the primary/unique key of the table).
You have to handle most of code the manually for this. OnClick of next button, highlight the next row from the search result. again traversing of the search result has to handled manually like keeping the track of current result, moving to next result or moving backward etc.
then on click of reset button clear the search result session and bind the grid again without any highlighted rows.

I don't have code to post for you right now. but i hope if you implement this approach surely your problems will be resolved.